# Does "chkdsk /r" harm your HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I've ran "chkdsk /r" about once or twice on my HDD and I was wondering if it causes any overheating or extreme wear and tear.

Comment: Short answer: no.  It doesn't do anything a HDD isn't designed to handle.  Nothing it does is extreme or wearing beyond normal usage (if you're talking about a HDD).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using `chkdsk /r`.  Its purpose is to find bad sectors on a hard drive.  It does this attempting to write to the drive and checking if the contents are correct.  A hard drive is meant to be written to.  Repeatedly and often.  There isnt much abuse a hard drive cant take from a standard user.  More than likely, you will replace the whole computer long before the hard drive fails.

Comment: Hard disks are by far the most likely to fail item on a PC - in excess of 5% in first year according to returns from my local large PC retailer. Dropping a hard drive at the wrong angle will damage it, as will vibration from other disks ( if it's not NAS ready).  I've replaced a lot more hard drives then computers in the systems I look after. Also, the probability of disk failure is the driving force behind RAID, and the likely hood of compound failure with use the reason why RAID5 is pretty much dead for any half decent disk capacity.

Comment: @davidgo  Lol.  your comment actually made me laugh.  While hard drives *are* the most likely part to break in a computer, that does *not* mean they are fragile and will break with usage.  Modern hard drives have extremely long MTBF ratings.  Your comment on RAID is meaningless in this context.  I have purchased and maintained thousands of computers and hard drive replacement has never been a factor.

Comment: I wonder if you have built a bit of a straw man.   I didn't use the word fragile (but I would describe them as robust either). I did not claim they will break with usage.  Care to evidence your assertions that " There isn't much abuse a hard drive cant take from a standard user. More than likely, you will replace the whole computer long before the hard drive fails."

Comment: Your statement " I have purchased and maintained thousands of computers and hard drive replacement has never been a factor." is disengenius (do you use SSD's) .  >1000 hard drives maintained and no hdd failures?  Yeah right.